# How to customize html text fields

Tags: html

I am making a login script that has six text fields the problem is it looks like this:

[image]

How do you center it and make the words apear inside the box?

EDIT: all I'm looking for currently is how to have the text in the box a certain color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were just looking for a cool design, here's what I came up with:

## Fiddle

Here is the HTML:

```
<form id="signup">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required="required" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required="required" />
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
    <input type="email" placeholder="Confirm Email" required="required" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required="required" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The styling you're gonna have to see for yourself..

:D

**EDIT:** To make the words inside appear in a certain color, put this in your CSS code -

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #999; }
:-moz-placeholder           { color: #999; }
::-moz-placeholder          { color: #999; }
:-ms-input-placeholder      { color: #999; }
```

(Obviously, change the `#999` to the color of your choice.)

That would cause the `placeholder`'s to appear in a certain color. If you were talking about the color of the text written, then just use

> input { color: #999; }

Comment: i have the exact same except without the submit button lemme update the picture

Comment: check the new picture

Comment: i want the second one but i did the color: option and it didnt work

Comment: to elaborate my problem is not with the color of the text but the color of the words First name etc

Comment: To make the words "First Name" in a different color, that's the first chunk of code in my edit, [Fiddle for your convenience](http://jsfiddle.net/K7k2L/2/)

Answer (score 1):

its called `placeholder`, where you say words appear inside the text box. Its an HTML5 attribute. Here's how you use it

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Username">
```

Comment: and how to center it i tried position:center; in css

Comment: position center the text? if that so, use `text-align:center;`

Comment: in my css i have `input {
 
 text-align:center;
}` but it doesn't work.

Comment: that  just centered the text inside the box

Comment: check this jsfiddle, it is centered when u put that css in http://jsfiddle.net/B5vpj/

Comment: well it still isnt centered on my screen even on the jfiddle could it be an outdated browser

Comment: I want the text box in the center of the page not the text in the center of the box

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working cross browser [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LUrjJ/)

You need `input[placeholder]` to target the placeholder element on some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I have centered it on the page by adding this to my css:

```
form {

    text-align:center;
}
```